# Identifying connector

Tags: connector, identification

I opened up my tablet  and found something really strange. It looked like an IC mounted on a plastic like substance. I am wondering what this actually is? Also what are these type of connectors called?

[image]

Comment: Assuming you mean the overall structure holding the other components as well it's not a connector it's a flexible PCB.

Comment: It would be hard to take a worse picture if you tried.

Comment: Are flex PCB's cheaper than normal PCB's?

Comment: They're usually more expensive; they're also quite fragile, especially when you have a huge rigid IC mounted on them like the photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a [polyimide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyimide) flexible PCB. It is either hot bar soldered or mates with a standard [flat flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_flat_cable) connector.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the connector you are referring to, but that plastic-like substance is a [flex PCB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_electronics). They are frequently used in consumer electronics where space is at a premium, as they are thin and can be used to implement cabling between circuits in different orientations and planes without the need for the space required by (and increased cost of) connectors and cabling.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_electronics

It's a flexible pcb.It is used in small devices because of space.The connector is called FPC Connector.You will find a lot on internet.